# How to set constraints from page control indicator to the view

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, constraints, swift3

Can anybody help me please?:)

How can I set constraints in a **storyboard** **for Page Control Indicator** so when I am listing my **collectionView pages** the indicator isn't moving.

I've tried setting constraints for page control indicator, but there is just option to set it with cell frame. So when I list a collection view indicator appears again and again on each new page.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Set pagecontroller width = View.Width 
And then add constraint 
1. Leading  (You can add x pixel space)
2 trailing  (You can add x pixel space)
3 Bottom. (You can add x pixel space)
4. Fix height

Comment: @DevThakur  Probably you didn't get my problem. 

The cell of a collection view is located on the whole screen. But I need to set constraints for page control indicator relating to View. When I am trying to set them, there is no option to set constraints with a view, just with a cell.

Comment: pagecontroller is inside cell or View ? 
if inside View then you can connect it easily 
if inside cell then you need to put it on View first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the currentpage in the pageControl. The best is at the function scrollViewWillEndDragging:

```
override func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

    let pageNumber = Int(targetContentOffset.pointee.x / view.frame.width)
    pageControl.currentPage = pageNumber

}
```

then it will work :)